# Kinetic energy vs Quantity of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, collision

I have to do an impact test for a project that I'm working for. The certified test says that I have to hit with an 25mm ice ball. Instead of that, I have a 250gr metal ball. The ice ball hits at 80 Km/h but I'm using gravity force to speed this ball. The question is, if I want to match the effect of the impact in both cases, Do I have to match Kinetic energy or Quantity of motion?

Comment: Define 'quantity of motion'.

Comment: Which effect of the impact are you measuring? Indentation?

Comment: Sorry, I'm spanish speaker so I don't know exactly how to traslate the expression. Kinetic energy is (1/2)*Mass*Speed². Quantity of motion is Mass*Speed. I need to check the material does broke or not by the ball.

Comment: The Quantity of Motion is called momentum.

Comment: how much does the ice ball weigh?

Comment: @Mark H: Ah, make sense: 'Cantidad de movimiento' in Spanish; 'Bewegungsgröße/Bewegungsmenge' in German; 'коли́чество движе́ния' in Russian;

Comment: @MarkH Genau! Das ist Korrekt!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your impact test is something like what is shown in the following video.

https://youtube.com/watch?v=6Hf6uPXJ6Y0

The amount of damage an impact produces is a function of its kinetic energy. However, notice that the ice ball is smashed apart in the test in the video. The initial kinetic energy of the ice ball is distributed between damaging the ice ball and the target. A metal ball will not receive as much damage because of its higher strength, so it will do more damage to the target. This makes it very difficult to compare results when using such different projectiles. I doubt any results you obtain will be accepted as valid.